# MapEntry - specify type annotation

Tags: flutter, dart, linter

I'm using a linter package to practice strict coding, however, I can't figure out how to solve this warning. The code is working but I just want to understand this warning and how to solve this. I'm new to flutter by the way. Hope someone can answer my question. TIA!

[Actual Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lzXd.png)

PS: sorry, unable to display image because of restriction

Comment: Don't screenshot your code. Instead, copy and paste it here and format it by selecting your entire code and by pressing `Ctrl + K`.

Comment: Yes I will next time. Thanks

Comment: You can edit your question and do it this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lint you're getting is from [pedantic](https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic)'s `always_specify_types` property. It means that you have to specify the type of the variable. In your case, you need to specify the type of your `MapEntry`. By default, `MapEntry`'s key and value's type will be `dynamic`. **You'd have to specify it as `MapEntry<int,Tab>`.**

In simple terms, instead of:

```
var number = 12; // dynamic means that the type can be anything (Eg: String, int, etc.)
```

do:

```
int number = 12;
```

Comment: `MapEntry` is not *always* equal to `MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>`.  In this case, the types would be *inferred* since the first argument is clearly an `int` and the second is clearly a `Tab`.  However, the `always_specify_types` lint wants *all* types to be explicit regardless of inference.

Comment: Thanks for telling me @jamesdlin. I removed that part.